# Dart VM initialization failed: Snapshot not compatible

Tags: dart

I just run `dart2aot main.dart main.aot` to compile my dart file to binary and it runs fine on windows, but when I try to `dartaotruntime main.aot` on another machine, with Linux OS (Ubuntu) it doesn't work, giving me that error:

`VM initialization failed: Snapshot not compatible with the current VM configuration: the snapshot requires 'product use_bare_instructions no-"asserts" no-causal_async_stacks no-bytecode x64-win' but the VM has 'product use_bare_instructions no-"asserts" no-causal_async_stacks no-bytecode x64-sysv`

How can I solve that? There is a way for me on a windows machine generate the aot for linux?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Vyacheslav Egorov on the Dart SDK team:

We currently don't support cross compilation of AOT snapshots using Dart SDK. To generate a snapshot for Linux you would need to run Linux version of the Dart SDK. (e.g. you could try using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10 for that)